# Cypher System Edge Application question

Tags: cypher-system

Effort costs 3 points from a pool on the first use and 2 on the second use. But this is only if the second use is from the same pool, as I understand it.
If it was from a different pool, it would cost another 3 points.
Am I right?

Answer (score 6):

### You normally only can use one pool

The rules for spending effort (p. 192) say:

> For every level of Effort spent on a task, the task’s difficulty
> decreases by one step. It costs 3 points from a stat Pool to apply one level of Effort, and it costs 2 additional points for every level thereafter (so it costs 5 points for two levels of Effort, 7 points for three levels
> of Effort, and so on). A character **must spend points from the same stat Pool as the type of task or roll** — Might points for a Might roll, Speed points for a Speed roll, or Intellect points for an Intellect roll.

So the task determines from which of the three stats you can spend level of Effort on. If you could somehow spend points from another stat pool, then this might count separately, but normally, you do not have that option.